# Oracle overwrites my Date?

Tags: oracle, date, jpa, insert

I got a problem with Oracle Dates. It seems that predefined Dates in an Java Application are different after inserting into an OracleDB.

Insert via JPA entity:

```
entity.setDateOfCreation(new Date(System.currentTimeInMillis())); 
// 1350565985000
```

After commit and retrieve:

```
entity.getDateOfCreation() // 1350565985047
```

Why is this different?

I assumed Oracle would just insert my specific Date Object with these exact Milliseconds into the Database. But obviously it doesn't. Because of the minimal delay it seems to "overwrite" the given Date with its own Date in milliseconds (and despite I do NOT use @GeneratedValue).

Comment: Where are you seeing the time ending 85000? And is the database column of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: The columntype is @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Comment: What is the data type of the actual column in the Oracle database?  An Oracle `DATE` does not store milliseconds-- an Oracle `DATE` just has precision to the second.  Is there any chance you've reversed the comments in your question?  If the `getDateOfCreation` was returning a value where the milliseconds were all 0 while the `setDateOfCreation` was passing in a value with milliseconds, that would be explainable if the data type of the Oracle column was a `DATE`.

Comment: Please post the table definition.  Thanks.

Comment: @Justin: thanks, you are actually right, I mixed up both times in milliseconds. The one with 000 on the end is the date which I read from the database. Can I insert the date without the milliseconds?

Comment: Ok I just made the input then by first formatting the Date with SimpleDateFormat (specifying the date without the milliseconds) and inserted it this way. It works, now both are the same! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table you working with have a trigger which populates that column?  I would hope it does.  I have experienced lots of problems in the last with time differences between the app server and the database.  It is much better to have a single of time which ensures consistent timings across the state.

Comment: Hello, thanks fo your participation. No, I can't see any Triggers for this table. It should be "clean".